# How do I merge two PDF files with attachments using itext?

Tags: itext

I am trying to merge two pdf files (file1.pdf and file2.pdf) into a single file file3.pdf. One of the source files, file2.pdf has few attachments.

Using PdfCopyFields addDocument method does not include the attachments in the source pdf files to the destination pdf file. How do I achieve this?

Extracting the document level attachments from source files using PdfDictionary and adding them to the destination file using PdfWriter addFileAttachment method works.

Can you please let me know if there is any other efficient method to include the attachments from source pdf files to be included in destination pdf file after merging?

This is the sample code that I am using to replicate the scenario.

```
public class TestItext
{
    public String[] attachments;
    public TestItext()
    {
        attachments = new String[2];
    }

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try
    {           
        TestItext obj = new TestItext();
        obj.extractDocLevelAttachments("C:\\source.pdf");

        obj.addAttachments("C:\\source.pdf","C:\\temp\\dest.pdf");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void extractDocLevelAttachments(String filename) throws IOException 
{
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(filename);
    PdfDictionary root = reader.getCatalog();
    PdfDictionary documentnames = root.getAsDict(PdfName.NAMES);
    PdfDictionary embeddedfiles = documentnames.getAsDict(PdfName.EMBEDDEDFILES);
    PdfArray filespecs = embeddedfiles.getAsArray(PdfName.NAMES);
    PdfDictionary filespec;
    PdfDictionary refs;
    FileOutputStream fos;
    PRStream stream;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < filespecs.size(); ) {
      filespecs.getAsString(i++);
      filespec = filespecs.getAsDict(i++);
      refs = filespec.getAsDict(PdfName.EF);

      for (Object key : refs.getKeys()) {

        fos = new FileOutputStream(String.format("C:\\temp\\"+ filespec.getAsString((PdfName)key).toString()));
        attachments[count++] = String.format("C:\\temp\\"+ filespec.getAsString((PdfName)key).toString());
        stream = (PRStream) PdfReader.getPdfObject(refs.getAsIndirectObject((PdfName)key));
        fos.write(PdfReader.getStreamBytes(stream));
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
      }
    }
    reader.close();
}
public void addAttachments(String src, String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException 
{
  PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
  PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
  for (int i = 0; i < attachments.length; i++) {
    addAttachment(stamper.getWriter(), new File(attachments[i]));
  }
  stamper.close();
}

protected void addAttachment(PdfWriter writer, File src) throws IOException {
  PdfFileSpecification fs =
    PdfFileSpecification.fileEmbedded(writer, src.getAbsolutePath(), src.getName(), null);
  writer.addFileAttachment(src.getName().substring(0, src.getName().indexOf('.')), fs);
}
```

}

Comment: The pivotal words here are *document level attachments* - Merging using iText happens on the page level and, therefore, does not carry across document level attachments. If you want to include document level stuff in your merged PDF, you have to add it explicitly which you already seem to do. If you do that the most efficient way, I cannot tell without seeing your code.

Comment: @mkl Thank you so much for you quick and informative response. I've edited the description and added the sample code which I used for testing the scenario. Can you please let me know if this is an efficient way to handle attachments or if there is any other better way at doing this?

Comment: At first glance the code looks ok. If you know the attachments aren't too big, you may consider keeping them in memory instead of writing them to disk. If you don't know, though, storing them temporarily in files is sensible.